# Sylius promotions workflow

Tags: sylius

i'm having some problems to understand how promotions work.
I understand what rules are and what actions are, and how they work, but i can't understand the workflow. 
When the entire process (check applicable promotions based on thei rules and then execute actions) starts? is it when the order is saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a promotion processor service in promotions bundle. 
And there is a listener in core bundle which uses it to apply promotions.

Please check https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/EventListener/OrderPromotionListener.php#L76